# Install conda default_packages through pip

Tags: python, conda, mini-forge

I have Miniforge installed on my computer.

Here is the part of my global .condarc configuration file that is of interest:

```yaml
create_default_packages:
  - <some_package>
```

I would like to know if there is a way to force conda to perform the installation of my default package <some_package> using pip or through a channel / URL of my choice (e.g https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages), but for that package only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, such functionality is not possible with any standard options. You could try [filing a feature request](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues).